# Hbase + Hadoop's MapReduce giving wrong sum with negative values

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I need to run MapReduce over `HBase` tables to sum `Double` values. I followed the example from the [HBase documentation](http://hbase.apache.org/book/mapreduce.example.html).

The attributes were stored initially by converting Strings to byte arrays (Using HBase's `Bytes.toBytes(value)`) but now I need to get them as `Double` to sum their values. For the columns that have positive values only, it gives me the correct sum, but I have a column that has some negative values too (it's called `diferenca` in the code below).

When I run this job, it gives me a wrong answer, and I noticed that it is as like as if the Reduce task is getting the module of the numbers, or something like that. But when I debug, I see that the parsed Double object `valor` is correctly negative. I don't know what is causing this...

The Job setting:

```
 job = new Job(hTable.getConfiguration(), "All");
            job.setJarByClass(HBaseQuery.class);
            scan.setCaching(500);
            scan.setCacheBlocks(false);
            TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(
                    tabela,        // input table
                    scan,               
                    CalculoTotaisMapper.class,     // mapper class
                    Text.class,         // mapper output key
                    DoubleWritable.class,  // mapper output value
                    job);
            TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob(
                    tabela,        // output table
                    CalculoTotaisReducer.class,    // reducer class
                    job);
            job.setNumReduceTasks(1);   // at least one, adjust as required

            boolean b = job.waitForCompletion(true);
```

My Mapper:

```
public class CalculoTotaisMapper extends TableMapper<Text, DoubleWritable> {

    public static final String[] ATTRS = 
      new String[]{"valortotalprestador", "valortotalconvenio", "diferenca"};


    private Text text = new Text();
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CalculoTotaisMapper.class);

    public void map(ImmutableBytesWritable row, Result value, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        Double val = 0.0;
        for (String attr : ATTRS) {
            byte[] valueBytes = value.getValue("hc".getBytes(), attr.getBytes());
            String valueString = Bytes.toString(valueBytes);

            val = Double.parseDouble(valueString);

            text.set(attr);

            context.write(text, new DoubleWritable(val));


        }

    }
}
```

My Reducer:

```
public class CalculoTotaisReducer extends TableReducer <Text, DoubleWritable,
                                                   ImmutableBytesWritable> {

    public static final byte[] CF = "qu".getBytes();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<DoubleWritable> values,
       Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        double i = 0.0;
        for (DoubleWritable val : values) {
            double valor =  val.get();
           i += valor;
        }

        Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("all"));
        put.add(CF, key.getBytes(), Bytes.toBytes(i));

        context.write(null, put);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your table contains negative values, and the job reads it correct. Then the sum is actually correct as well. Or do you want sum the absolute value? Try `i += Math.abs(valor)`.

Comment: The job is summing as if it was using `Math.abs`, but I really want the job to sum in the normal way, summing the negatives values as they are.